# Connection dies after exception from mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, c3p0

When I get an exception from mysql like the following exception

```
19:36:35,712 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]  - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
19:36:35,713 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]  - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
org.springframework.dao.PessimisticLockingFailureException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: could not execute statement
```

That specific connection becomes in a bad state then 10 minutes later I get the following error

```
19:48:41,859 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection]  - [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
19:48:41,859 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection]  - [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 716,308 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 716,308 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem
```

Usually when an application level exception happens, the transaction rollbacks and the connection can be used for future requests.

How can I achieve the same with an exception from Mysql?

I use java spring hibernate mysql and c3p0

Here's the config

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.delimiter=;
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=250
hibernate.c3p0.checkout_timeout=120000
hibernate.c3p0.test_connection_on_checkin=true
hibernate.c3p0.idle_connection_test_period=300
hibernate.archive.autodetection=class
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

The code is either inside a @Transactional function

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(
            rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Long create() {
       //Hibernate and queryDsl code
    }
```

Or sometimes I have to manage the transaction manually like this because I don't want to rollback if the last function fails. I believe this is the function that is causing issues.

```
public void function(){
try {
    final TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    final TransactionStatus transactionStatus = platformTransactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
    try {
        //Hibernate and QueryDsl code

        entityManager.flush();
        platformTransactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        LOG.error(t);
        platformTransactionManager.rollback(transactionStatus);
        entityManager.clear();
        throw t;
    }
    // Call a transactional function
    transactionFunction();
}
```

}

**EDIT**

Removed the part about the duplicate key error as I can confirm now that it's irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Spring moved from c3p0 to HikariCp, can you consider changing connection pool?

Comment: Try to clear session in your script.

Comment: @PeterDarmis I do call entitymanager.clear() but the connections are still in a bad state after a wait timeout exception

Answer (score -1):

It's because of badly managed live sessions or options for doing everything even querying or because of poorly choiced Transaction Isolation level

Comment: I think you should delete every line in your config file except the dialect and run

Answer (score -1):

try changing this settings:
- wait_timeout default value 28.800 seconds.
- interactive_timeout default value 28.800 seconds.
- innodb_lock_wait_timeout default value 50 seconds. (if you are using INNODB)

p.s: the 2nd error is about duplicate entry in your data, in field that you use as a PRIMARY KEY, maybe you need to check on your duplicate data sent to the mysql